# Python 3.4 import name errors

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import RiotAPI from Riot API

```
from RiotAPI import RiotAPI

def main():
    api = RiotAPI('f9a42fb0-a584-4bd2-813f-480e5067a898')
    r = api.get_summoner_by_name('aeipownu')
    print (r)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I am getting the error:

```
"ImportError: cannot import name 'RiotAPI'.

Traceback < most recent call last>:

File "C:\Users\Massimo\Python\Main.py", line 1 in < module>

from RiotAPI import RiotAPI

ImportError: cannot import name 'RiotAPI':
```

I know this error has to do with Python 3.4 importing not going to the correct libraries but I don't know how to fix it. I've searched a solution and it seems that you either have to rename the file or change the `syspath` or put it into a directory. How do I do any of these solutions? What exactly is changing a filename? It's not simply renaming it. Not sure how to fix this problem

Comment: You gave out your API key in the code sample. [Riot specifically says not to do this](https://developer.riotgames.com/discussion/riot-games-api/show/oomYkEK4) when asking for coding help. Contact Riot and ask them to deactivate this key and generate a new one for you.

Comment: Where is the RiotAPI module coming from? I can't find any reference to it anywhere. How did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have not installed RiotAPI
install it using

```
python -m pip install RiotAPI
```